# Query compleja en Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo las siguientes tablas y sus campos

Añado el modulo de datos para que se vea todo mas claro de como esta montado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me piden una query que me parece bastante compleja,llevo dos días dando vueltas y probando cosas, dice así:

> Se desea obtener la media de edad de las atletas femeninas, ganadoras de medalla (oro, plata o bronce), para las distintas modalidades de ‘Gimnasia artística’. 
>   Analizad los posibles contenidos del campo `result` a efectos de devolver solo los valores esperados, aun cuando no existieran datos de algún valor concreto para el conjunto de registros mostrados por la consulta. 
>   En concreto, se desea que se muestre el indicador de género de las atletas, la medalla obtenida, y la media de edad de dichas atletas. Se calculará la edad restando de la fecha del sistema `(SYSDATE)`, la fecha de nacimiento de la atleta, dividendo dicho valor por 365. A efectos de evitar mostrar los decimales, truncad `(TRUNC)` el resultado del cálculo de la edad.
>   Ordenad los resultados por la edad media de los atletas.

Pues bien ahora mismo tengo esto:

```
select person.gender,score.score,competition.idcompetition
from person,athlete,score,competition
where person.idperson= athlete.idathlete    and
athlete.idathlete = score.idathlete  and
score.idcompetition<> competition.idcompetition  
and person.gender='F' and competition.idsport=18
group by 
person.gender,
score.score,
competition.idcompetition
```

Y me saca esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo varios problemas,lo primero es que no usamos `joins` y para juntar las tablas lo hacemos con igualaciones, "NombreTabla.CampoTabla" = "NombreTabla.CampoTabla".
Por otra parte tengo un problema con sacar la edad de las athletas ya que el campo birthday es char,se me ocurrio esto `((sysdate - p.birthday) / 365) age` pero no me funciona supongo que por ser un char,aparte tengo que usar la funcion `trunc` y ademas allar la media de las edades supongo que con la funcion `AVG`.

Luego solo tienen que salir las athletas que ganan un medalla "Silver","Golden" o "Bronze" que eso sale de la tabla `score` y el campo `score`.

Se que estoy muy cerca pero no consigo lo que se me pide.

Comment: que quiere decir esto en un join? score.idcompetition<> competition.idcompetition  O sea, todos los score que no sean de esa competencia?

Comment: @gbianchi si pongo el = no me sale ningún resultado es muy extraño ya que lo unico que hago es relacionar el resultado con la competicion mediante su clave primaria.Es mas acabo de quitar esa relacion y el resultado es el mismo,si quito la linea "score.idcompetition<> competition.idcompetition  " Me funciona igual

Comment: ¿Estás publicando el modelo completo? Pregunto porque no le veo sentido a tablas como `Athlete` y no me queda clara la relación entre `Competition` y `Score`.

Comment: El query te pide 3 campos. Genero que siempre va a ser F, la medalla y la media de edad de la medalla... Lo primero que tenes que hacer es un query que muestre esas tres cosas, solo para las condiciones que necesitas. el join tiene que ser si o si por = para todos los casos.. pero tene en cuenta que podes solucionarlo con subquerys, lo cual seria mas que recomendable en este caso.

Comment: @gbianchi si,eso lo tengo claro tengo que sacar el sexo que es F el score que solo puede ser "silver,golden o, bronze" pero no se como decirle eso y por otra parte el tema de la edad de los que ganan algo no se sacarlo como me piden con el system y lo de la media de edad...Me lo piden todo en una consulta que intuyo tendrá subconsultas pero no consigo que me saque solo las competiciones que tengan un score,me saca todas incluso las que no...

Comment: Ahi te agregue 3 cuartas partes de tu ejercicio resuelto. Si tenes alguna otra duda, segui preguntando ;)

Answer (score 0):

Esta clase de querys complejos se resuelve de atras para adelante, utilizando subquerys (que puede no ser el metodo mas efectivo en algunos casos, pero sirve para entender la logica)..

Lo primero que hay que hacer, es traer las competiciones donde se ganaron medallas. Para eso, necesitamos las tablas score y competition.

```
select s.IdAthlete, s.Score 
from SCORE s inner join COMPETITION c on c.IdCompetition = s.IdCompetition 
where c.IdSport = 18;
```

Este query nos trae todos los atletas que ganaron una medalla para el deporte 18.

Ahora, este resultado lo queremos filtrar solo por los atletas femeninos. Para ello tenemos que mezclarlo con la tabla personas, saltando desde atletas (no entiendo esto que haya dos tablas, pero supongo que sera por el tema equipos).

```
select p.gender, p.birthday, s.Score 
from (
    select s.IdAthlete, s.Score 
    from SCORE s inner join COMPETITION c on c.IdCompetition = s.IdCompetition 
    where c.IdSport = 18) s inner join ATHLETE a on a.IdAthlete = a.Score
    inner join PERSON p on p.IdPerson = a.IdPerson 
where person.gender='F'
```

Este query, nos trae esos tres campos solo para atletas femeninas para el deporte 18.

Y ahora lo que falta es cerrar el ejercicio, agrupando por genero, Medalla (score) y aplicando la funcion de media correspondiente (avg, mediam, no se cual te pidio tu profesor).

Ademas hay que transformar esas fechas en años, como dice el enunciado. Y eso es importante que lo hagas antes de calcular la media y el group...

Comment: Puff estoy fuera de casa ahora mismo,en cuanto llegue pruebo y le doy mas vueltas y comento que me sale y demas....Me queman las ganas de llegar a casa y probar!!

Comment: Tengo problemas para que el campo score.score solo me traiga "Silver","Gold" y "Bronze"....Pongo esto score.score='Silver' pero cuando añado Gold y Silver no me funciona...¿Como añado mas? Un saludo!

Comment: Porque querrias hacer eso? Hay mas datos ademas de esos tres? si es asi, modifica tu pregunta y agrega **TODA** la informacion que es relevante a la pregunta.

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta con todo para que se entienda todo mucho mejor.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta,mis principales problemas son el tema de la fecha de nacimiento usando el sysdate y teniendo en cuenta que el campo es char, otro problema es que no usamos joins y por ultimo la media de la edad con la funcion AVG.

Comment: @Roman345 Estas usando algo que se llama join implicitos (o explicitos). El resultado es exactamente el mismo. Sacas los joins y pone la condicion de join en el where... si es char la fecha (por dios), lo primero que vas a tener que hacer es un cast para pasarla a fecha. Y seguis sin decir que viene en el campo score. pero si pueden venir otras cosas, es cuestion de igualara ese campo a esos 3 valores, para que no traiga los que sean distintos de eso.

Comment: en el campo score de la tabla score puede devolver Gold,silver,bronze o diploma y como solo piden las mujeres que ganan medalla por eso lo de no incluir el diploma...No saco esta consulta,ya me tiene desesperado

Comment: @Roman345 score <> "diploma" para que no traiga los diplomas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las aportaciones pero doy la query por imposible,me faltaria sacar la media de las edades del campo person.birthdate que me volvi loco y no lo consigo..La query en general es una locura pero bueno...Intentado esta a mas no poder.

Comment: La query es bastante simple. En realidad estas a medio camino. hacela por pasos. Si hasta donde esta le agregas que solo traiga las medallas, solo te falta calcular el avg.. y para eso tenes que agrupar...